# how to use llvm intrinsics @llvm.read_register?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I noticed that `llvm.read_register()` could read the value of stack pointer, as well as `llvm.write_register()` could set the value of stack pointer. I add main function to the `stackpointer.ll` which could be found in the llvm src:

```
;stackpointer.ll  
 define i32 @get_stack() nounwind {  
 　%sp = call i32 @llvm.read_register.i32(metadata !0)  
 　ret i32 %sp  
}

declare i32 @llvm.read_register.i32(metadata) nounwind  
!0 = metadata !{metadata !"sp\00"}

define i32 @main() {  
　%1 = call i32 @get_stack()  
　ret i32 %1  
}
```

I tested on an armv7 board running ubuntu 11.04:

```
lli stackpointer.ll
```

then, I get a stack dump:

```
ARMCodeEmitter::emitPseudoInstruction  
UNREACHABLE executed at ARMCodeEmitter.cpp:847! 
Stack dump:  
0.　　Program arguments: lli stackpointer.ll  
1.　　Running pass 'ARM Machine Code Emitter' on function '@main'  
Aborted
```

I also tried llc:

```
llc stackpointer.ll -o stackpointer.s
```

The error messege:

```
Can't get register for value!  
UNREACHABLE executed at ARMCodeEmitter.cpp:1183!   
Stack dump:  
0.　　Program arguments: llc stackpointer.ll -o stackpointer.s  
1.　　Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on moulude 'stackpointer.ll'  
2.　　Running pass 'ARM Instruction Selection' on function '@get_stack'  
Aborted
```

I also tried on x86-64 platform, it didn't work. What is the correct way to use these intrinsics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My lli didn't like your metadata definition.

I cnagned your

> `!0 = metadata !{metadata !"sp\00"}`

to

```
!0 = !{!"sp\00"}
```

And it worked. (Well, since I'm on x86-64, I have also changed everywhere i32 to i64 and sp to rsp).

Plus there were bad whitespace symbols in your formatting, but I think it might be due to StackOverflow/html or something).

Comment: It seems that the llvm version matters. I'm currently using llvm 3.4.2, and my lli couldn't accept the syntax you listed above. which version do you use? As for the white space, I left it intentionally.

Comment: @winter333 I use a rather new version of LLVM built from source: 3.7.0svn

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I download the llvm 3.6 pre-built binaries, and it works!